# Access to the jEdit variables from SuperAbbrevs template

Tags: plugins, beanshell, jedit

I wonder if there is any way how to access jEdit variables (like the buffer variable) from the beanshell inside SuperAbbrevs plugin template.

When I try to expand following template, the error `Attempt to resolve method: getName() on undefined variable or class name: buffer` appears int Activity log.

```
<#= buffer.getName() #>
```

When I try to run this code in the BeanShell console then it displays the current buffer name:

```
buffer.getName()
```

Is it possible to access buffer name from the SuperAbbrevs template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see from a quick look at that plugins sources, those variables are not forwarded to the templates. Only the variables you define in the options of the plugin and additionally `filename` and `selection`.

In your example `filename` is exactly what you want, so `<#= filename #>` works for inserting the name of the file. If you would need more, you would probably need to issue a plugin feature request.